# What Data Structure is the best suited for working with Search algorithms?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, search, collections

I have a task where I need to implement a fully written Search algorithm to search according to the content of the Month and display all of the corresponding data from different data files.

What Data Structure is best suited to store my data so that I can:

1. Apply Binary Search algorithm on it.
2. Store the data in a corresponding way.

Take a look at how my Data is currently stored in the Array:

[image: Now]

And this is what I'm aiming for:

[image: After]

As you can see from the After image I edited quotation marks around the Months column, this is to make it clear that I want to search the data according to the content of the Month. *(e.g. When I use the algorithm to search for all the "January" Months all the January values get printed out along with their corresponding data).*

I am trying to store the data with these conditions:

1. The values from different arrays still correspond to eachother.
2. I am able to apply Search algorithm on the data and search corresponding data according to the content of the Month.

It's really hard for me to word this problem in a concise, easy to understand way, I hope this is not too confusing. I've been struggling with this problem for dozens of hours and can't seem to find a solution from anywhere.

This is how I store my arrays:

```
  //Read in the files and put them into arrays.
        String[] Years = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Year_1.txt");
        String[] Months = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Month_1.txt");
        String[] Days = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Day_1.txt");
        String[] Times = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Time_1.txt");
        String[] Depths = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Depth_1.txt");
        String[] Latitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Latitude_1.txt");
        String[] Longitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Longitude_1.txt");
        String[] Magnitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Magnitude_1.txt");
        String[] Regions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Region_1.txt");
        String[] IRIS_IDs = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\IRIS_ID_1.txt");
        String[] Timestamps = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Timestamp_1.txt");


        //Creating an array of months and adding corresponding data from other arrays. 
        string[] MonthsArray = new string[Days.Length];
        //Since all files have same number of items, using any array.Length will iterate through all the items.
        for (int i = 0; i < Days.Length; i++)
        {
            MonthsArray[i] = string.Format("{0,10} {1,6} {2,6} {3,9} {4,7} {5,7} {6,7} {7,7} {8,29} {9,9} {10,9}", Months[i], Years[i], Days[i], Times[i], Magnitudes[i], Latitudes[i], Longitudes[i], Depths[i], Regions[i], IRIS_IDs[i], Timestamps[i]);
        }
        //Creating an array of Years and adding corresponding data from other arrays.
        string[] YearsArray = new string[Days.Length];
        //Since all files have same number of items, using any array.Length will iterate through all the items.
        for (int i = 0; i < Days.Length; i++)
        {
            YearsArray[i] = string.Format("{0,6} {1,10} {2,6} {3,9} {4,7} {5,7} {6,7} {7,7} {8,29} {9,9} {10,9}", Years[i], Months[i], Days[i], Times[i], Magnitudes[i], Latitudes[i], Longitudes[i], Depths[i], Regions[i], IRIS_IDs[i], Timestamps[i]);
        }
```

This is my Binary Search algorithm which counts the occurrences of duplicates so that I can print out all the searched values:

```
public static int Binary_Search<T>(T[] data, int n, T Search, bool searchFirst, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = n - 1;
        int result = -1;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (comparer.Compare(data[mid], Search) == 0)
            {
                result = mid;
                if (searchFirst)
                    high = mid - 1;
                else
                    low = mid + 1;
            }
            else if (comparer.Compare(Search, data[mid]) < 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is how I perform the Binary  Search on already sorted array and display the searched values:

```
 Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the name of the Month to display all the seismic Data in that month.");
                Console.Write("Month: \n");
                var Search1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int firstIndex1 = Binary_Search(MonthsArray, MonthsArray.Length, Search1, true, Comparer<string>.Default);
                if (firstIndex1 == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count of {0} is {1}", Search1, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    int lastIndex = Binary_Search(MonthsArray, MonthsArray.Length, Search1, false, Comparer<string>.Default);
                    //Count the occurrence of duplicate elements and display the searched value per each occurrence.
                    int occurence = lastIndex - firstIndex1 + 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < occurence; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthsArray);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of searched items found in the array: {0}", occurence);
                }
                break;
            }
        break;
```

---

Class for the Data with their corresponding data types.

```
    public class SeismicData
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public double Time { get; set; }
        public double Depth { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Magnitude { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public int IRIS_ID { get; set; }
        public int TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

---

My QuickSort Algorithm:

```
   //QuickSort method for ascending arrays. Takes in any data type array and sorts it.
    public static void QuickSort<T>(T[] data)
    {
        Quick_Sort(data, 0, data.Length - 1, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }
    //Second QuickSort method for case 2 for Descending the array.
    public static void QuickSort<T>(T[] data, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        Quick_Sort(data, 0, data.Length - 1, comparer);
    }
    //QuickSort algorithm using comparer
    public static void Quick_Sort<T>(T[] array, int left, int right, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int i, j;
        T pivot, temp;
        i = left;
        j = right;
        pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
        do
        {
            while ((comparer.Compare(array[i], pivot) < 0) && (i < right)) i++;
            while ((comparer.Compare(pivot, array[j]) < 0) && (j > left)) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i <= j);
        if (left < j) Quick_Sort(array, left, j, comparer);
        if (i < right) Quick_Sort(array, i, right, comparer);
    }
```

Comment: Create a **CLASS** to hold all those fields, and use proper **Data Types** such as `DateTime` to represent your data.

Comment: @Idle_Mind My data is in the class now what?

Comment: Update your post with your new Class...then we'll go from there.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Updated my post with my new Class

Comment: You should consider changing to DateTime instead of separate Year, Month, Day and Time fields.  Trust me, you'll thank me later.  Now that you've got your Class "SeismicData", you want to get rid of "MonthsArray" and instead create a `List<SeismicData>` to hold your instances.  You'll still use a loop but with each iteration you create a dynamic instance of SeismicData, populate its fields, then add it to your `List<SeismicData>`.  Once you've got that accomplished you can use **LINQ** or other mechanisms to filter the records you want.

Comment: is the assignment specific to binary search? there are more optimal hash table data structures like `Dictionary` and `Lookup`. .NET also has a lot of binary search methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch

Comment: @Slai It's specific to Custom made search algorithms, not allowed to use any built in algorithmic functions

Comment: Are you allowed to **SORT** using the built-in methods?  Implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) on your SeismicData class so it sorts by the DateTime variable data type I keep mentioning.  Once your List<SeismicData> is sorted, you can then use any of your custom search algorithms (such is a manually implemented binary search).

Comment: @Idle_Mind I've made a Quick Sort algorithm to sort the data in either Ascending or Descending order. Edited the post with the algorithm

Comment: @Idle_Mind I am struggling to find a way to put my [Year, Month, Day and Time data](http://puu.sh/vJ1gs/8e384f1ad9.png) into a DateTime data structure, I get stuck on the most annoying problems..

Comment: @Ulfren : "It's specific to Custom made search algorithms, not allowed to use any built in algorithmic functions" is it because this is an assignment? or is there a genuine reason for this?

Comment: You'd use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert all the combined parts as a string to a DateTime.  Since you have the month as a word, you'll need to specify the culture/provider as [new CultureInfo("en-US")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).  Build up your format pattern using the codes in [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You should refactor your question to shorter one for readibilty